# Unchecked cast at generic kotlin factory

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm trying to make a generic factory in kotlin for parsing some string into Model classes:

```
internal interface Model

data class UserId(val id: String, val name: String, val link: String): Model
data class Shelf(val id: String, val name: String, val bookCount: Int): Model

internal inline fun <reified T: Model> getParser(): Parser<T> {
    return when (T::class) {
            UserId::class -> UserIdParser() as Parser<T>
            Shelf::class -> UserShelvesParser() as Parser<T>
            else -> throw Exception("can't match proper parser")
        }
}

internal interface Parser<out T: Model> {
    fun parse(xml: String): T
}


internal class UserIdParser : Parser<UserId> {
    override fun parse(xml: String): UserId {
        return parseUserId(xml)
    }
}

internal class UserShelvesParser : Parser<Shelf> {
    override fun parse(xml: String): Shelf {
        return parseShelf(xml)
    }
}
// for example
internal fun parseUserId(xml: String) = UserId("123", "owl", "ya.ru")
internal fun parseShelf(xml: String) = Shelf("123", "to-read", 20)
```

So in client code, I could write this:

```
val t = getParser<UserId>().parse("")
```

It works, but at `getParser` method I've got warning `Unchecked cast from UserIdParser to Parser<T>`. How could I achieve such behavior in kotlin, without the warnings in idiomatic way?

Comment: I'm not sure you have to cast `as Parser<T>` in the when statement as `UserIdParser` and `UserShelvesParser` are already extending `Parser<T>`. This way the type is precise and not trying to guess what `T` is in `Parser<T>`.

Comment: If I remove this cast, I've got Type mismatch error: Required Parser<T> and found UserIdParser.

Comment: This will not work either because it's reified generic type param and not an instance of some class - T is not an expression

Comment: You may move the cast outside the `when` block - thus you will have only one warning instead of two.

Comment: Yes) but this is lowering the bar) I wonder if any way exists to express this simple concept without the warnings at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly different from what you are aiming for, but it works without any warning:

```
internal interface Model

data class UserId(val id: String, val name: String, val link: String) : Model
data class Shelf(val id: String, val name: String, val bookCount: Int) : Model

internal inline fun <reified T : Model> parse(xml: String) = when (T::class) {
    UserId::class -> parseUserId(xml)
    Shelf::class -> parseShelf(xml)
    else -> throw Exception("can't match proper parser")
} as T

// for example
internal fun parseUserId(xml: String) = UserId("123", "owl", "ya.ru")

internal fun parseShelf(xml: String) = Shelf("123", "to-read", 20)
```

then it can be called like that:

```
val t = parse<UserId>("")
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: If you write it this way, the warning will be gone, but you are returning base Model types and not the child concrete types, such as UserId or Shelf and then the client should cast to an appropriate concrete class, which kinda makes the whole idea useless

Comment: I edited my answer, adding a cast after the when statement, and it now returns the concrete type.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works! Apparently, the problem was with nested generics types like Parser<T> and probably compiler can't infer the types but with simplification, to just T, all work out.